# Synology cron job not working

Tags: linux, cron, scheduled-task, synology

I am not sure where to ask this question but I'll ask here first.

I've got a Synology DS211 server and I am trying to run cron jobs but it is not working.

This is the code I got in the crontab file

```
10 19 4 * * root /opt/bin/openssh-scp user@remote-server:/home/user/Backup/backup.tar.gz /volume1/Backup/
```

However it is not running.

I am able to run commands with `/opt/bin/openssh-scp` directly, but not with cron

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: If this command prompts your for a password, it will not work as cron job. Is this the case?

Comment: It does not require a password, public key installed on remote-server

Answer (score 1):

I've got cronjobs working on our DS1010+.  In order to do this I had to add the jobs to `/etc/crontab` and then run `/usr/syno/etc.defaults/rc.d/S04crond.sh stop` followed by `/usr/syno/etc.defaults/rc.d/S04crond.sh start`

Instead of running those last 2 commands you can just reboot the NAS instead.  As Khaled says you'll also need to make sure that you have keys set up so that you don't need to enter a password for the SCP.

Comment: I have already tried restarting the service using `synoservice --restart crond` and have also tried restarting the NAS. It still does not work.

Comment: In that case I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "tabs" to separate the entries not spaces.

Comment: I don't think that that is correct. http://helpdocs.westserver.net/v3/sitemanager/Using_Cron.htm

Comment: It is correct on Synology.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an option for you, but the Synology DSM software (versions 4.2 and up) includes a task scheduler feature. For all I know it may simply be converting it to a crontab job under the covers, but perhaps trying it out from the admin GUI may get the job done and help avoid any syntax issues.

Answer (score -1):

DS211 using CHIP MV6282 so you can install bootstrap and then install ipkg, then install crond.
This crond work well like any other linux, unix systems.

Do not use the default crontab of synology DSM.